# No increase in Reputation points

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

For the past two days, there seems to be some problem with my reputation. For instance, I received 7 up-votes for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts). However, there has been no change in my reputation. I noticed a similar bug around a month back.

Comment: this is documented in http://math.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get any reputation for community wiki answers or questions. This isn't a bug; it's a feature.

Comment: Ok. Thought so. Thanks.